# Python Script to Find and Move Files

Tags: python, shutil

The purpose of the below python code is to find all the .jpg files included in any folder within the rootdir1 path and move all the files to the targetfolder.

When I spot checked the work of the code, I found a few jpg that were not copied to the target folder.  What am I missing in the code?

```
import os
import shutil

RootDir1 = r'/Users/brianwuollet/Desktop/Takeout'
TargetFolder = r'/Users/brianwuollet/Desktop/Photos'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk((os.path.normpath(RootDir1)), topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.jpg'):
            print "Found"
    SourceFolder = os.path.join(root,name)
    shutil.copy2(SourceFolder, TargetFolder) #copies file to target folder
```

Answer (score 2):

You should  fix the indentation:

```
import os
import shutil

RootDir1 = r'/Users/brianwuollet/Desktop/Takeout'
TargetFolder = r'/Users/brianwuollet/Desktop/Photos'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk((os.path.normpath(RootDir1)), topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.jpg'):
            print "Found"
            SourceFolder = os.path.join(root,name)   #<--- Here is the change
            shutil.copy2(SourceFolder, TargetFolder) #<--- Here is the change
```

Right now you're copying outside the loop, so not all the files copied

Comment: I think those lines you marked should be indented one further.  Otherwise you'll be copying *all* files, ending in .jpg or not.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation of your code is incorrect. The lines:

```
SourceFolder = os.path.join(root,name)
shutil.copy2(SourceFolder, TargetFolder) #copies file to target folder
```

will be executed only once for each directory traversed by `os.walk()` resulting in just one file being copied from each directory. Change your code to this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk((os.path.normpath(RootDir1)), topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.jpg'):
            print "Found"
            SourceFolder = os.path.join(root,name)
            shutil.copy2(SourceFolder, TargetFolder) #copies file to target folder
```

Now each file that ends with '.jpg' will be copied.

It's also possible that you might overwrite files with the same base name, and this could result in lost files if you were actually *moving* the file instead of just copying it. You could check whether a file with the same name already exists in the target directory, and then print a warning, or somehow rename the file when copying it.